# Position Fixed Problems

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, height, css-position

I'm building an interface for mobile and desktop and it have a sidebar menu which is supposed to have always 100% of the window height(not the document height) and keep at fixed position while I scroll the right area down and up.

On Mac Safari the position:fixed; works ok, but when I scroll the left one, and it reaches the end, it scrolls the page and lose it's fixed position. That's what happens on MAC SAFARI.. In all of the other browsers the position fixed is simply ignored by the browser.

Here: I made a video showing my problem: http://youtu.be/OqqDYnQDO6c

In the video I start with Mac Safari and at 0m44s I change to Mac Chrome. Both the last released version.. Firefox, opera and all windows browsers don't work too.

It was supposed to work as like most of the mobile apps, with fixed sidebar with scroll

I don't know what to do anymore searched web a lot but nothing was helpful.

I would appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Comment: Again, absolutely not OK. You need to show us the problem in the question. Linking to a video which shows your question is absolutely and completely antithetical to how this site works. Do not do this. Further, you deleted the link to the code, now this question is useless. The entire purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide canonical answers to questions; it is *required* that your question remain useful to others after it solves your problem. Please stop linking to off-site code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a block of CSS that says

```
/**----- ESTILOS -----**/
*{text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Removing

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

will allow the page to fix-position the left menu appropriately in Chrome, while removing

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

will allow the page to fix-position the left menu appropriately in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you very much, solved the problem.